# Creating excel graph with 2 variables

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a graph in excel (thinking about a scatter graph) with two variables. I have day of the week and and time of day. I would like Day of the Week to be on the Y axis and Time of Day on the x-axis. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are your day and time in two different columns (or rows)? Is the day text like "Monday" or a number 1-7? Can you show any sample data?

Comment: When time is shown on one axis, the other usually shows something happening on those dates/times. Why would you want to plot time against time?

Comment: @TomSharpe  - The column contains the days and the row has hours (e.g. 5hr, 6hr, ... 4hr.

Comment: It should work - can you let us know if you are hitting a particular problem with it?

Comment: @TomSharpe, I would like the y axis to be label Monday - Sunday and the x axis to 5hr through to 4hr. at the moment the Y axis is showing the values.

Comment: You can do it by putting the y-axis values in as dates and formatting them as dddd to show Monday, Tuesday etc. Will post result later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the day values as dddd as mentioned in the comment. Here's an example. I have chosen the numbers in the Day column so that if represented as a date they start from Monday.

I also fixed the min and max of the y-axis to 2 and 8, and the min and max of the x-axis to .125 and .75 (because each hour=1/24 of a day so to get an exact number it's easier to work in multiples of 3 hours or 1/8 of a day).

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was very useful